# Selection can not be launched

Tags: java, java-8

I tried to create this simplest program and platform showed me this ,how can i resovlve situation? Thanks !

[image]

Comment: [Similar questions](https://www.google.com/#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+eclipse+unable+to+launch+the+selection)

Comment: Because the signature of your `main` method is wrong. It must have a `String[]` parameter. Your `main` method has no parameters. It must be `public static void main(String[] args)`.